# Using Firebase Storage for Uploading Images

Tags: swift

I can only upload a single photo to FirebaseStorage.

All the tutorials I have seen on youtube use FirebaseStorage to save user's profile pictures. However, I am trying to make a restaurant app where I should be able to keep several pictures and not only one. My code right now only allows me to keep one. As soon as I try to upload a second image, it erases the first one.

Here's my code:

```swift
@IBAction func agregarComidaFav(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let imageData = imagen?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
            return
        }
                
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://comidas-68043.appspot.com")
        let storageProfileRef = storageRef.child("ComidasFavoritas")
        
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/png"
        storageRef.child("comidasFavoritas/png").putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetaData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                return
            }
        }
        
        storageProfileRef.downloadURL(completion: {  (url, error) in
            if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                print(metaImageUrl)
                self.imagenURL = metaImageUrl
            }
        })
        
        var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
        ref = db.collection("comidasFavoritas").addDocument(data: [
            "imagenURL" : imagenURL
            
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error agregando comida: \(err)")
            } else {
                let id = ref!.documentID
                print("Comida agregado con ID: \(id)")
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
storageRef.child("comidasFavoritas/png").putData(...)
```

...guarantees that each time, the data is going to be written to `"comidasFavoritas/png"`

I don't know anything about how you're keeping track of your data/images in your app, but you'll probably need some way to keep track of an ID for that image. Then, when you store it, you could store it like:

```
storageRef.child("comidasFavoritas/png\(imageId)").putData(...)
```

You'd probably also want to store that ID in your database when you store the image URL.